# Как убрать нижний и верхний колонтитулы при печати страницы?

Tags: javascript, html

Как убрать нижний и верхний колонтитулы при печати страницы командой

```
window.print()
```

из скрипта на javascript?

Comment: так ли важно избавляться от колонтитулов?

Comment: Да, одно из требований

Comment: Под колонтитулами я имею ввиду заголовок с датой и названием страницы и подпись внизу страницы содержащую ссылку и номер страницы. Вот как от них избавиться? Кто знаком с данной задачей, поделитесь пожалуйста решением!